# Determining an adequate lens for collimation

Tags: optics, lighting

I'm looking to develop an optical system to collimate a LED that is going to be fitted to glasses. I have a 5 mm diameter de-domed [LED](https://au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Lumileds/L150-5790500600000?qs=%2Fha2pyFadujgCJjuvOS59NZIKmNKM2FwFMH6%252Bj0gIaY6biCyMovrGg%3D%3D) with a circular aperture that I need to produce a clean and even beam with minimal spill. The projected image is to be around 200 mm in diameter from 500-700 mm away. I would like to use off the shelf lenses or lens to produce this, all while fitting in a package similar to the photos attached.

[image: Headlight]
[image: Package and emitted beam]
[image: Beamshot]

A Fresnel lens is deemed to be the best option based on my elementary knowledge. However, none of the similar products use one. They seem to be a combination of aspheric or ball lenses.

I understand that placing a LED at the focal length of a lens produces a collimated image. However, where do things such as die size, projected image size and distance, light through put, and etc, come into play?
What steps do I need to take in order to develop a final product?

Comment: You may want to investigate Kohler Illumination. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6hler_illumination?wprov=sfti1

Comment: @EricS The headlight in the images sell for $20. I'm not developing anything new or doing something revolutionary; the link you provided overcomplicates things and serves no purpose. I just need to find a guide, so I can do the calculations and select a lens. This isn't a theoretical question, just a simple straightforward one

Comment: I was just trying to suggest the best way to get uniform illumination. You should add the additional information about the device to your question.

Comment: Question asks for collimation, someones close vote says "Needs more focus", made me chuckle a little

Comment: My experience is to use optical design software with ray tracing to analyze such things. I'm not up on the best free options but I did find this: https://3doptix.com

Comment: I am no expert in optics, but I don't *think* those things really come into play at all. All you need is to put the LED at the focal distance of a lens. Any old convex lens. You should pay attention to the focal distance since it affects the size of your device. And because the light rays are collimated, you need a 200mm lens to create a 200mm spot.